# Как сделать отращение размера элемента только верхней части, а не в целом?

Tags: jquery

[image: вот так]Проблема состоит в том, что когда пишу animate с 20px до 40px, то блок в целом трансформируется. А мне надо, чтобы эти добавочные 20 пикселя добавлялись к верхней части только. Дело в том, что у меня 2 элемента друг на друге и мне надо при наведении на верхний слой, нижний слой, точнее ТОЛЬКО верхняя ее часть возросла на 20 пикселей.

Comment: `padding-top: 20px; margin-bottom: 0;`

Comment: растет вниз =/

Comment: тогда:

@navi1893, Согласно правилам форума, вопросы не должны сводиться к решению либо завершению учебных заданий за учащихся. Пожалуйста, уточните, что вы сделали сами и что не получилось.

**выложите код** сюда и на jsfiddle

Comment: На чем-то похожий вопрос, я уже как-то отвечал. [Тот пример](http://jsfiddle.net/Deonis/VRFbk/) не буду переделывать, т.к. вам главное суть уловить.

Comment: @eicto а я что попросил весь проект за меня собрать разве??? Это один элемент, говорю как вот такое сделать? А что вы ждете чтоб я выложил сюда??? Как я 2 слоя друг на друге держу??? Не надо попусту пихать мне правила форума!

Comment: @Deonis это я тоже без проблем соорудить смогу. Но я хочу сделать так, чтобы при наведении размер элемента изменялся так: +20пкс сверху, +80пкс снизу обростал. Вот к чему мой вопрос, в принципе

Comment: делаю padding-left:15px - работает. А вот padding-right под ним же не работает

Comment: @navi я хочу чтобы вы выложили сюда пример кода с ошибкой а не вашу картинку.

Answer (score 1):

Вас понял, вот тогда такое решение:
http://jsfiddle.net/ZQBuu/4/

Comment: Можете объяснить? Я чет не понял :/

Comment: здесь мы для нижнего блока задаем событие $('#up').animate({height: 40}), которое увеличит верхний элемент до 40px при наведении(на нижний. Если я правильно понял ваш вопрос то так!

Comment: Прикрепил рисунок к вопросу

Comment: @Артур Пантелеев не надо вставлять onmouseover="" да еще и с кодом jQuery внутри. смотрится кошмарно. а вообще - [вот](http://jsfiddle.net/oceog/ZQBuu/6/)

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/szYQq/1/

Вот мой код, но он все еще вниз открывается =/ @eicto

Comment: вот неужели было сложно выложить вместо того чтобы нахамить ? http://jsfiddle.net/oceog/szYQq/2/ http://jsfiddle.net/oceog/szYQq/3/ http://jsfiddle.net/oceog/szYQq/4/

Comment: я реально стараюсь что то придумать, но что то не поддается =/

Comment: @navi сами посчитайте